# scipy.optimize Constrained Minimization SLSQP - Cannot Match the target 100%

Tags: python, math, optimization, machine-learning, scipy

I am trying to get the minimized weight that's closer to average weight combined. My current problem is using the SLSQP solver I cannot find the right weight that meet the target 100%. Is there another solver I could use to solve my problem? Or any math suggestions. Please help.

My math right now is

```
           **min⁡(∑|x-mean(x)|)**

           **s.t.** Aw-b=0, w>=0


           **bound** 0.2'<'x<0.5
```

Data

```
  nRow# Variable1   Variable2   Variable3   

  1 3582.00 233445193.00    559090945.00    

  2 3394.00 217344811.00    496500751.00    

  3 3356.00 237746918.00    493639029.00    

  4 3256.00 219204892.00    461547877.00    

  5 3415.00 225272825.00    501057960.00    

  6 3505.00 242819442.00    505073223.00    

  7 3442.00 215258725.00    490458632.00    

  8 3381.00 227681178.00    503102998.00    

  9 3392.00 215189377.00    487026744.00    

    w1          w2                     w3
  Target    8531.00 429386951.00    1079115532.00
```

Question: Find the minimized weight that are closer to average

---

Python Code:

```
A = np.array([[3582.000000, 3394.000000, 3356.000000, 3256.000000, 3415.000000,
        3505.000000, 3442.000000, 3381.000000, 3392.000000],
       [233445193.000000, 217344811.000000, 237746918.000000,
        219204892.000000, 225272825.000000, 242819442.000000,
        215258725.000000, 227681178.000000, 215189377.000000],
       [559090945.000000, 496500751.000000, 493639029.000000,
        461547877.000000, 501057960.000000, 505073223.000000,
        490458632.000000, 503102998.000000, 487026744.000000]])

b = np.array([8531, 1079115532, 429386951]) 

n=9
def fsolveMin(A,b,n):

    # The constraints: Ax = b

    def cons(x):
        return A.dot(x)-b

    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':cons},

            {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x:x[0]})

    # The minimizing constraints: the total absolute difference between the coefficients

    def fn(x):
        return np.sum(np.abs(x-np.mean(x)))       

    # Initialize the coefficients randomly
    z0 = abs(np.random.randn(len(A[1,:])))

    # Set up bound
   # bnds = [(0, None)]*n

    # Solve the problem

    sol = minimize(fn, x0 = z0, constraints = cons, method = 'SLSQP', options={'disp': True})



    #expected 35%
    print(sol.x)
    print(A.dot(sol.x))

    #print(fn(sol.x))

print(str(fsolveMin(A,b,n))+"\n\n")
```

Comment: You made this a difficult NLP (not differentiable non-linear programming problem). I would formulate this as an LP (linear program); this way you get a proven global optimum.

Comment: @Erwin. How would you add constrain on to the linear programming piece?

Comment: I detailed my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you an idea how **bloated** this will get with low-level tools like scipy's [linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) **as we have to mimic their standard-form**:

The basic idea is to:

- add an auxiliary-variable for the mean, like Erwin proposed
- add n-auxiliary-variables to handle the absolute values [like documented in lpsolve's docs](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/absolute.htm)
- (and i'm using n-extra-aux-vars as temp-vars for `x-mean`)

Now this example works.

For your data you have to be careful in regards to the bounds. Make sure, the problem stays feasible. The problem itself is pretty unstable as hard-constraints are used for `Ax=b`; usually you would minimize some norm / least-squares here (no LP anymore; QP/SOCP) and add this error to the objective)!

It might be needed to switch the solver from `method='simplex'` to `method='interior-point'` at some point (only available since scipy 1.0).

Alternative:

Using [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html), formulation is much easier (both variants mentioned) and you get quite a good solver (ECOS) for free.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=120)
np.random.seed(1)

""" Create random data """
M, N = 2, 3
A = np.random.random(size=(M,N))
x_hidden = np.random.random(size=N)
b = A.dot(x_hidden)  # target
n = N

print('Original A')
print(A)
print('hidden x: ', x_hidden)
print('target: ', b)

""" Optimize as LP """
def solve(A, b, n):
    print('Reformulation')
    am, an = A.shape

    # Introduce aux-vars
    # 1: y = mean
    # n: z = x - mean
    # n: abs(z)
    n_plus_aux_vars = 3*n + 1

    # Equality constraint: y = mean
    eq_mean_A = np.zeros(n_plus_aux_vars)
    eq_mean_A[:n] = 1. / n
    eq_mean_A[n] = -1.
    eq_mean_b = np.array([0])

    print('y = mean A:')
    print(eq_mean_A)
    print('y = mean b:')
    print(eq_mean_b)

    # Equality constraints: Ax = b
    eq_A = np.zeros((am, n_plus_aux_vars))
    eq_A[:, :n] = A[:, :n]
    eq_b = np.copy(b)

    print('Ax=b A:')
    print(eq_A)
    print('Ax=b b:')
    print(eq_b)

    # Equality constraints: z = x - mean
    eq_mean_A_z = np.hstack([-np.eye(n), np.ones((n, 1)), + np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n))])
    eq_mean_b_z = np.zeros(n)

    print('z = x - mean A:')
    print(eq_mean_A_z)
    print('z = x - mean b:')
    print(eq_mean_b_z)

    # Inequality constraints: absolute values -> x <= x' ; -x <= x'

    ineq_abs_0_A = np.hstack([np.zeros((n, n)), np.zeros((n, 1)), np.eye(n), -np.eye(n)])
    ineq_abs_0_b = np.zeros(n)

    ineq_abs_1_A = np.hstack([np.zeros((n, n)), np.zeros((n, 1)), -np.eye(n), -np.eye(n)])
    ineq_abs_1_b = np.zeros(n)

    # Bounds
    # REMARK: Do not touch anything besides the first bounds-row!
    bounds = [(0., 1.) for i in range(n)] +     \
             [(None, None)] +                   \
             [(None, None) for i in range(n)] + \
             [(0, None) for i in range(n)]

    # Objective
    c = np.zeros(n_plus_aux_vars)
    c[-n:] = 1

    A_eq = np.vstack((eq_mean_A, eq_A, eq_mean_A_z))
    b_eq = np.hstack([eq_mean_b, eq_b, eq_mean_b_z])

    A_ineq = np.vstack((ineq_abs_0_A, ineq_abs_1_A))
    b_ineq = np.hstack([ineq_abs_0_b, ineq_abs_1_b])

    print('solve...')
    result = spo.linprog(c, A_ineq, b_ineq, A_eq, b_eq, bounds=bounds, method='simplex')
    print(result)
    x = result.x[:n]
    print('x: ', x)
    print('residual Ax-b: ', A.dot(x) - b)
    print('mean: ', result.x[n])
    print('x - mean: ', x - result.x[n])
    print('l1-norm(x - mean) / objective: ', np.linalg.norm(x - result.x[n], 1))

solve(A, b, n)
```

Output:

```
Original A
[[  4.17022005e-01   7.20324493e-01   1.14374817e-04]
 [  3.02332573e-01   1.46755891e-01   9.23385948e-02]]
hidden x:  [ 0.18626021  0.34556073  0.39676747]
target:  [ 0.32663584  0.14366255]
Reformulation
y = mean A:
[ 0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333 -1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
y = mean b:
[0]
Ax=b A:
[[  4.17022005e-01   7.20324493e-01   1.14374817e-04   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  3.02332573e-01   1.46755891e-01   9.23385948e-02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
Ax=b b:
[ 0.32663584  0.14366255]
z = x - mean A:
[[-1. -0. -0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -1. -0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0. -1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
z = x - mean b:
[ 0.  0.  0.]
solve...
     fun: 0.078779576294411263
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 10
   slack: array([ 0.07877958,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07877958,  0.        ,  0.76273076,  0.68395118,
        0.72334097])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.23726924,  0.31604882,  0.27665903,  0.27665903, -0.03938979,  0.03938979,  0.        ,  0.03938979,
        0.03938979,  0.        ])
x:  [ 0.23726924  0.31604882  0.27665903]
residual Ax-b:  [  5.55111512e-17   0.00000000e+00]
mean:  0.276659030053
x - mean:  [-0.03938979  0.03938979  0.        ]
l1-norm(x - mean) / objective:  0.0787795762944
```

Now **for your original data**, things get tough!

You need to:

- scale your data as the magnitude of your variables will hurt the solver

  - depending on your task you might need to analyze the effects of scaling / invert it
- use the interior-point solver
- be careful with the bounds

Example:

```
A = np.array([[3582.000000, 3394.000000, 3356.000000, 3256.000000, 3415.000000,
        3505.000000, 3442.000000, 3381.000000, 3392.000000],
       [233445193.000000, 217344811.000000, 237746918.000000,
        219204892.000000, 225272825.000000, 242819442.000000,
        215258725.000000, 227681178.000000, 215189377.000000],
       [559090945.000000, 496500751.000000, 493639029.000000,
        461547877.000000, 501057960.000000, 505073223.000000,
        490458632.000000, 503102998.000000, 487026744.000000]])
b = np.array([8531., 1079115532., 429386951.])

A /= 10000.  # scaling
b /= 10000.  # scaling

bounds = [(-50., 50.) for i in range(n)] +     \
...

result = spo.linprog(c, A_ineq, b_ineq, A_eq, b_eq, bounds=bounds, method='interior-point')
```

Output:

```
solve...
     con: array([  3.98410760e-09,   1.18067724e-08,   8.12879938e-04,   1.75969041e-03,  -3.93853838e-09,  -3.96305566e-09,
        -4.10043555e-09,  -3.94957667e-09,  -3.88362764e-09,  -3.89452381e-09,  -3.95134592e-09,  -3.92182287e-09,
        -3.85762178e-09])
     fun: 52.742900697626389
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 8
   slack: array([  5.13245265e+01,   1.89309145e-08,   1.83429094e-09,   4.28687782e-09,   1.03726911e-08,   2.77000474e-09,
         1.41837413e+00,   6.75769654e-09,   8.65285462e-10,   2.78501844e-09,   3.09591539e-09,   5.27429006e+01,
         1.30944103e-08,   5.32994799e-09,   3.15369669e-08,   2.51943821e-09,   7.54848797e-09,   3.22510447e-09])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ -2.51938304e+01,   4.68432810e-01,   2.68398831e+01,   4.68432822e-01,   4.68432815e-01,   4.68432832e-01,
        -2.40754247e-01,   4.68432818e-01,   4.68432819e-01,   4.68432822e-01,  -2.56622633e+01,  -7.91749954e-09,
         2.63714503e+01,   4.40376624e-09,  -2.52137156e-09,   1.43834811e-08,  -7.09187065e-01,   3.95395716e-10,
         1.17990950e-09,   2.56622633e+01,   1.10134149e-08,   2.63714503e+01,   8.69064406e-09,   7.85131955e-09,
         1.71534858e-08,   7.09187068e-01,   7.15309226e-09,   2.04519496e-09])
x:  [-25.19383044   0.46843281  26.83988313   0.46843282   0.46843282   0.46843283  -0.24075425   0.46843282   0.46843282]
residual Ax-b:  [ -1.18067724e-08  -8.12879938e-04  -1.75969041e-03]
mean:  0.468432821891
x - mean:  [ -2.56622633e+01  -1.18805552e-08   2.63714503e+01   4.54189575e-10  -6.40499920e-09   1.04889573e-08  -7.09187069e-01
  -3.52642715e-09  -2.67771227e-09]
l1-norm(x - mean) / objective:  52.7429006758
```

**Edit**

Here a SOCP-based least-squares (soft-constrained) approach, which i would recommend in terms of numerical-stability! This approach can and should be tuned for whatever you need. It's implemented using the already mentioned [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/) modelling-tool using the ECOS solver.

The basic idea:

- **instead of**: `min(l1-norm(x - mean(x)) st. Ax=b`
- **solve**: `min(l2-norm(Ax-b) + c * l1-norm(x - mean(x)))`

  - where `c` is the nonnegative trade-off parameter
  - small `c`: `Ax=b` is more important
  - big `c`: `x - mean(x)` is more important

Example code & output for your data and bounds of `-50, 50` and `c=1e-3`:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

""" DATA """
A = np.array([[3582.000000, 3394.000000, 3356.000000, 3256.000000, 3415.000000,
        3505.000000, 3442.000000, 3381.000000, 3392.000000],
       [233445193.000000, 217344811.000000, 237746918.000000,
        219204892.000000, 225272825.000000, 242819442.000000,
        215258725.000000, 227681178.000000, 215189377.000000],
       [559090945.000000, 496500751.000000, 493639029.000000,
        461547877.000000, 501057960.000000, 505073223.000000,
        490458632.000000, 503102998.000000, 487026744.000000]])
b = np.array([8531., 1079115532., 429386951.])
n = 9

# A /= 10000.  scaling would be a good idea
# b /= 10000.  """

""" SOCP-based least-squares approach """
def solve(A, b, n, c=1e-1):
    x = cvx.Variable(n)
    y = cvx.Variable(1)             # mean

    lower_bounds = np.zeros(n) - 50  # -50
    upper_bounds = np.zeros(n) + 50  #  50

    constraints = []
    constraints.append(x >= lower_bounds)
    constraints.append(x <= upper_bounds)
    constraints.append(y == cvx.sum_entries(x) / n)

    objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm(A*x-b, 2) + c * cvx.norm(x - y, 1))
    problem = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)

    problem.solve(solver=cvx.ECOS, verbose=True)

    print('Objective: ', problem.value)
    print('x: ', x.T.value)
    print('mean: ', y.value)
    print('Ax-b: ')
    print((A*x - b).value)
    print('x - mean: ', (x - y).T.value)

solve(A, b, n)
```

Output:

```
 ECOS 2.0.4 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +2.637e-17  -1.550e+06  +7e+08  1e-01  2e-04  1e+00  2e+07    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  -
 1  -8.613e+04  -1.014e+05  +8e+06  1e-03  2e-06  2e+03  2e+05  0.9890  1e-04   2  1  1 |  0  0
 2  -1.287e+03  -1.464e+03  +1e+05  1e-05  9e-08  4e+01  3e+03  0.9872  1e-04   3  1  1 |  0  0
 3  +1.794e+02  +1.900e+02  +2e+03  2e-07  1e-07  1e+01  5e+01  0.9890  5e-03   5  3  4 |  0  0
 4  -1.388e+00  -6.826e-01  +1e+02  1e-08  7e-08  9e-01  3e+00  0.9458  4e-03   7  6  6 |  0  0
 5  +5.491e+00  +5.683e+00  +1e+01  1e-09  8e-09  2e-01  3e-01  0.9617  6e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0
 6  +6.480e+00  +6.505e+00  +1e+00  2e-10  5e-10  3e-02  4e-02  0.8928  2e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0
 7  +6.746e+00  +6.746e+00  +2e-02  3e-12  5e-10  5e-04  6e-04  0.9890  5e-03   1  0  0 |  0  0
 8  +6.759e+00  +6.759e+00  +3e-04  2e-12  2e-10  6e-06  7e-06  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0
 9  +6.759e+00  +6.759e+00  +3e-06  2e-13  2e-10  6e-08  8e-08  0.9890  1e-04   2  0  0 |  0  0
10  +6.758e+00  +6.758e+00  +3e-08  5e-14  2e-10  7e-10  9e-10  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=2.0e-10, reltol=4.7e-09, abstol=3.2e-08).
Runtime: 0.002901 seconds.

Objective:  6.757722879805085
x:  [[-18.09169736  -5.55768047  11.12130645  11.48355878  -1.13982006
   12.4290884   -3.00165819  -1.05158589  -2.4468432 ]]
mean:  0.416074272576
Ax-b:
[[  2.17051777e-03]
 [  1.90734863e-06]
 [ -5.72204590e-06]]
x - mean:  [[-18.50777164  -5.97375474  10.70523218  11.0674845   -1.55589434
   12.01301413  -3.41773246  -1.46766016  -2.86291747]]
```

This approach will always output a feasible solution (for our task) and you can then decide on the observed residual if it works for you.

As you observed, a lower-bound of 0 is deadly, in all formulations (look at the magnitude difference in your data!).

Here a lower-bound of 0 will get you a solution with some high residual-error.

E.g.:

- `c=1e-7`
- bounds = `0 / 15`

Output:

```
Objective:  785913288.2410747
x:  [[ -5.57966858e-08  -4.74997454e-08   1.56066068e+00   1.68021234e-07
   -3.55602958e-08   1.75340641e-06  -4.69609562e-08  -3.10216680e-08
   -4.39482554e-08]]
mean:  0.173406926909
Ax-b:
[[ -3.29341696e+03]
 [ -7.08072860e+08]
 [  3.41016903e+08]]
x - mean:  [[-0.17340698 -0.17340697  1.38725375 -0.17340676 -0.17340696 -0.17340517
  -0.17340697 -0.17340696 -0.17340697]]
```

Comment: Thanks Sascha. I am definitely getting close. I am getting the following error msg. message: 'Optimization failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point.'

Comment: I mentioned possible problems and things to check and do. So: (1) make sure the problem is still feasible after editing bounds (2) use the interior-point solver (which also detects infeasibility) (3) drop the lp-hard-constraint way and formulate a SOCP.

Comment: Thank you sascha. I adjusted my bound and got the answer I wanted. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi Sascha, when I set my bound to be 0 to 50. it gives me an error msg of 'The algorithm terminated successfully and determined that the problem is infeasible. ' Can you help?

Comment: Yes... either there is no nonnegative x solution or you ran into numerical trouble. Both i did mention. This is impossible to debug from here and even if, sometimes it's hard to explain to people why this and that is not working right, if they don't know the internals of those solvers. (i more or less already mentioned, that the model you are trying to optimize is very unstable; hard-constraints on Ax=b)

Comment: @StructureMesh I added a SOCP-LS prototype which will always be feasible. Be sure to understand the concept and implications. Also: cvxpy might be harder to setup!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Can you give me some pointers on how to modify the solver?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Looking at the socp-based least-squares approach. The l bound is set to be 0 but there are still negative x being returned by the the cvxpy solver. At this time, is it safe to say we have exhausted our options with existing packages and solver. The next approach is to make modification or create new solver

Comment: No! The next step is an introductionary course in numerical-optimization! These values have a negative sign, but they are like 1e-8 ~ 0. With limited-precision / floating-point math and iterative algorithms, this is normal and expected! And don't expect to be able to write a solver as good as these. These are highly complex (don't modify them) and written by experts. They also work on well-defined problems. The only better solvers are commercial ones (which might might output the same, or round; only in LP-type problems, they might use the more exact Simplex on top of the IPM-method).

Comment: And *"[...] and add this error to the objective)!"* I would like to get sure that I understand you well. Do you mean computing the (squared) residual(s) twice ? I.e. in the constraint as such AND in the objective, the latter being sum-augmented by it ?

Answer (score 0):

First introduce a free variable mu with the constraint:

```
   mu = sum(i, x(i))/n
```

Then introduce non-negative variables `y(i)` with:

```
   -y(i) <= x(i) - mu <= y(i)
```

Now you can minimize

```
   min sum(i,y(i))
```

This is now a straight LP (linear objective and linear constraints) and can be solved with any LP solver.